# Concatenate Table Columns Return Blank Access 2010

Tags: ms-access

I have a table in Access 2010 with three text columns, `First Name` and `Last Name`. I have a third calculated text column in the table named `Full Name`.

In Design View of the table I have set the Data Type of `Full Name` to Calculated, with an expression `[First Name]+" "+[Last Name]`.

This works fine providing there is data in `First Name` and `Last Name`; if either is blank the calculated field `Full Name` will be blank too - I can't seem to make it return the data that is present.

Any ideas? I'm sure it's something quite simple I'm doing, but it's driving me a little nutty.

Cheers

Rich

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
Nz([First Name],"") +" "+ Nz([Last Name],"")
```

for more info please check [MS Access: Nz Function](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/nz.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  iif(isnull(fname),lName, iif(isnull(lname),fname , fname+lname))  from tbl_emp
```

Answer (score 0):

Cheers Saghir. I did this but got an error that I couldn't use the Nz function in a calculated field. On the basis of this though I found I could use this in the 'Expression' field and it works perfectly.

[First Name]+" "+IIf([Last Name] Is Null,"",[Last Name])

So cheers!

- R

Comment: instead of Posting as answer kindly comment on respective answer.